# proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot 2^{n-k}=2^{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Is the equation true?

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot 2^{n-k}=2^{n+1}$

I tried Generating function but didn't get anything.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using binomial theorem.

Comment: @user291957 tried that too

Comment: This question has been asked on MSE tonnes of times. Did you bother looking at the solutions in the bottom right corner?

Comment: @JohnC: even for $n=0$...

Comment: :p deleted the comment to confirm the calculations, I'm not that good with numbers, yep, it fails miserably...

Comment: @Alex well, sorry but i dont see it in the bottom right corner.

Comment: @roy: well, you don't see $it$, but you can see a lot of similar stuff and try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General approach: 'pull out' $2^n$ out of the sum - it's a constant. You are left with an expression of the form
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k a^k
$$
where $0<a<1$ and the general term is $b_k = k a^k$ . Consider using perturbation method, namely:
$$
S_n + b_{n+1}  = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k a^k + (n+1)a^{n+1} 
$$
now to some algebreaic transformation on RHS and you'll get something geometric. Can you handle from here?

EDIT: 
OK, what you need are 
$$
V_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k a^k\\
$$
then
$$
V_{n} + b_{n+1}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k a^k + (n+1) a^{n+1} = 1 +\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1) a^{k+1} = 1 +  a V_n + a \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^k 
$$
Now do a bit of algebra, use the geometric sum for $\sum_{k} a^k$ and you got your result!

Comment: im not familiar with that method (perturbation).

Comment: well familiarize yourself then! It's a great and flexible method, often better than induction

Comment: if you can extend a bit how to proceed that would be great.

Comment: Ok, see the edit

Comment: thanks  ill try to read about this method.

Comment: It's from 'Concrete Mathematics' by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik

Comment: great book just saw now!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Roy. 
While trying to prove the statement using Induction, it fails to satisfy the first step.
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (n\cdot 2^{n-k}) = 2^{n+1}$$
Let's try n=1,
$$ \therefore LHS: 1\cdot (2^{1-0}) + 1\cdot (2^{1-1}) = 2+1 = 3$$
However
$$ RHS: 2^{1+1}=2^2=4$$
And LHS is not equal to RHS.

Comment: Oh sorry. :) I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to check $$\sum_{k=0}^nk\left(\frac12\right)^k=2$$

We know,
$$\sum_{r=0}^n x^r=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Differentiate wrt $x$

Now multiply either sides by $x$

The answer is $n$ needs  $\to\infty$

Comment: The sum $\sum_{k=0}^n{k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}$ cannot be independent on $n$ being a sum of positive numbers.

Comment: @M.Strochyk, But, that's implied the first line of the Question, right? What if $n\to\infty?$

Comment: The equality $\sum_{k=0}^n{k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}=2$ does not hold for any _finite_ $n$ as it is stated in OP's question.

Comment: @M.Strochyk, I'm yet to find "finite" though in the Question.